# run R distance function on Hadoop

Tags: r, hadoop

I have a series of R data frame (thousands). Each one has a categorical variable (productId), and a continuous variable (sales). I also have a distance function I have created (my_distance), that computes the distance between two productID's in the same data frame. Since there are hundreds of productIDs in each data frame and thousands of data frames, I wanted to explore the opportunity of using Hadoop to speed up the process.
Right now I'm using a for loop to iterate on all data frames, and mcmapply to calculate all distances between productIDs in a given dataframe.
I was wondering if this could be done in Hadoop to leverage parallel computing on my cluster's nodes.
Do not pay attention to the content of the distance function as it is only an example.

```
library(parallel)
library(reshape2)

calcDist <- function(x1, x2) {
  return(sqrt(sum(x1^2-x2^2)))
}

my_distance <- function(df, id1, id2) {
  x1 <- df[df$productId==id1,c('sales')]  
  x2 <- df[df$productId==id2,c('sales')]
  distx <- calcDist(x1, x2)
  return(distx)
}

productId <- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
sales <- runif(length(productId), min=0, max=100)

df <-data.frame(productId,sales)


...mcmapply()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workable solution, note that your function is sometimes returning `NaN`, which I have not investigated as your question seems more directed towards the overall procedure.

I used `localhost` as workers, you just need to replace the `hostNumbers` with a character vector of the names of the nodes on the cluster, or initialize the cluster however you already do. As long as you call it in place of `devClust` the mapply will work.

```
# define supporting data structures 
productId <- rep(c(1, 2, 3), each = 4)
sales.gen <- function() runif(length(productId), min = 0, max = 100)
df.gen <- function(x) data.frame(productId, sales = sales.gen())
dfList <- lapply(as.list(1:10), df.gen)

library(parallel)
on.exit(stopCluster(devClust))

# here you should use a vector of your nodes' names
hostNumbers <- c("localhost")

# builds a list structure of host names, one per node
hostFrame <- lapply(hostNumbers, function(x) list(host = x));

# replicates each node `kCPUs` times, so number of cpus on each node is equal
# NOTE: total number of workers cannot exceed 128 in base R!
kCPUs <- 2 
hostList <- rep(hostFrame, kCPUs);

# initialize the socket cluster, outfile = "" specifies that individual cpu commands & logs be printed to stdout, w
# which will be our log file for R.
devClust <- makePSOCKcluster(hostList)

# define functions
calcDist <- function(x1, x2) {
  return(sqrt(sum(x1^2-x2^2)))
}

my_distance <- function(df, id1, id2) {
  x1 <- df[df$productId==id1,c('sales')]  
  x2 <- df[df$productId==id2,c('sales')]
  distx <- calcDist(x1, x2)
  return(distx)
}

# export function definitions to cluster
functionDefs <- Filter(function(x) is.function(get(x, .GlobalEnv)), ls(.GlobalEnv))
clusterExport(devClust, functionDefs)

# run distance calcs. Note that we quote the function because it has 
# already been exported to the workers so there is no need to serialize again
list.of.distance.calcs <- clusterMap(devClust, 'my_distance', dfList, MoreArgs = list(id1 = 1, id2 = 2))
```

Comment: @ADJ, did this solution not suffice? Is there a way it could be improved?